# ARRAYFORMULA: COUNIF in Googlesheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, countif

I am facing the probem of COUNTIF with ARRAYFORMULA in googlesheet as below

1. Picture A working fine when I need to count in C.
2. Picture B can not working with arrayformula

Any one have solution to fix it ?

Thanks alot.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, CountIf can not be used like you are suggesting in an array.  If you put it in an array, all values will be counted in the range.  That being said, this can be achieved with a slight workaround.

```
=Array_Constrain(iferror(sort({row(B:B)-row(B1)+2-match(sort(B:B),sort(B:B),0),SORT(ROW(B:B)+2-row(B1)+2,B:B,1)},2,1),),9^9,1)
```

This formula will allow you to get a running count of the values in Column B.  Have a great day!

Comment: Thank you so much, that works GREAT, thats really HELP.

Comment: @TuPHAN You are welcome.  If the formula answers your question, you can mark it as answered.  Have a good night!

Answer (score 4):

use:

```
=INDEX(IF(A:A="",,COUNTIFS(B:B, B:B, ROW(B:B), "<="&ROW(B:B))))
```

[image]